# Python - optimise array routine

Tags: python, arrays, nested

I have two 2D arrays of about 80 000 rows (and a few columns) each. I have two nested for loops that take ages to process (because 80000*80000 is big).

The first block creates an array from some external data.

```
arrayIn = [[]]
del arrayIn[0]
# use arrayIn.append() to add mixed lists to each row
# example arrayIn.append(['dogs2443', 'cats12332', 3])
```

Then I copy an ID from this array into a new array, but checking to make sure that an ID is only added once. I tried using the `in` command, but it didn't work because I was comparing a String to an array element.

```
allNodes = [[]]
del allNodes[0]
for row in arrayIn
    add = True
    for node in allNodes:
        if row[0] == node[0]:
            add = False
    if add:
        allNodes.append(row[0])
```

Then it copies the index from the new array back to the original array to make accessing elements in the new array more easily:

```
for row in arrayIn:
    for index, node in enumerate(allNodes, start=0)
        if row[0] == node[0]
            row[0] = index
```

So there are quite a few things:

1. My array creation method means I have to awkwardly `del` the first element.
2. The IDs I'm using are String data type. Would making it an integer/long speed it up?
3. Would using a completely different structure speed it up? `Numpy` or something else?
4. It seems to get progressively slower as it proceeds. Is there anything I can do with memory? It's running on a powerful computer.
5. Perhaps there's a clever way to combine these two steps that I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using generator? Then you can pipeline different steps / stages which will result in significant speed up.